# Difference between Suspending Recurring Profile and Canceling Recurring Profile

Tags: php, magento

When a Customer Buy a Recurring Profile Product and In his/her Customer Dashboard > Recurring Profile > Profile Id We See Three buttons Cancel,Update,Suspend . Can someone Tell me the Working of All three??

Answer (score 1):

According to the Magento Documentation for Recurring Profiles:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/working-with-recurring-profiles

> - Pending – the profile is not active yet. The recurring profile start    date specified by the customer is in the future. A profile of
>     this    state can be either canceled by clicking the Cancel button or 
>     activated by clicking the **Get Update button**. The recurring profile
>     becomes active in Magento only after it is activated in the payment
>     system.
> - Active – a regular state for receiving instant payment notifications from the payment system and for receiving payments. A
>     profile of such state can be either suspended or canceled by clicking
>     he corresponding buttons. The store administrator can activate a
>     suspended recurring profile by clicking the Activate button.
> - **Suspended** – a temporary inactive profile. A profile of such state can be either activated or canceled. A recurring profile can be
>     suspended by the customer or the store administrator; it can also be
>     automatically suspended by the payment system when a scheduled payment
>     fails (if this is set up in the payment profile settings).
> - **Canceled** – a permanently inactive profile. A recurring profile can be canceled by either the customer or the store administrator.
> - Expired – a profile gets such status when its subscription period is completed.